# Electricity from an Atom

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

For someone maybe stupid question but im quite curious and didnt find an answer for this.

1. If elecricity is just a flow of electrons and we can power things by
   movement of electrons, Why we cannot get electricity/energy from
   electrons that are orbiting every atoms nucleus.

   - Is it related to uncertainity of the position of the electron or that the
     electrons of atom are not orbiting in the same direction?
   - Or it is related to the charge of the whole atom and we actually cant separate the energy of electron and nucleus.
2. Is it possible for the electrons of an atom to stop orbiting its nucleus.

Thank you for your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a great mystery in physics a century ago. According to classical physics an electron orbiting a nucleus should radiate electromagnetic waves and (very quickly) spiral in to the nucleus.

It can be shown mathematically that the Schrodinger Hamiltonian with an attractive 1/r potential ($1/r^2$ force) is bounded below, so there is a lowest energy state. This is in part due to the uncertainty principle but also depends on the form of the potential. For a $1/r^2$ (or stronger) potential the Hamiltonian can be unbounded below so you could extract infinite energy.

[John Baez](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/the-inverse-cube-force-law/) has a nice discussion of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually because of a slight adjustment needed in your first assumption.  Electricity is not *just* the flow of electrons.  It's the flow of electrons from a high potential to a low potential.  Within an atom, the electron remains at a constant potential, so there is no work to be gained.

It's similar to how we can use a waterwheel to capture the power from water flowing from a high altitude to a lower altitude, but we cannot capture power from the Brownian motion of the moving water molecules in a lake.  There is movement, it's just not from a high potential to a low potential (gravitational potential, in this case), so we can't generate work from it.

Comment: But I thought that every electron does give a tiny current which why a magnet work ? Is it not ?

Comment: Ok but potential (high, low) is just a reason for electron to move. same as gravity is reason why water flows down but if we make water flow by something else we still can get energy from it because its moving.. How is this different in electron / electricity?

Comment: We can't just get energy from any moving thing.  It has to move in ways which are conducive to harvesting work from them.  Electrons moving in an atom are simply not moving in one of those ways.  Going much further is difficult because the deeper nature of electrons "orbiting" a nucleus involves pointing out that they actually don't "orbit" the nucleus.  The answer is far more complicated and involves quantum mechanics and probabilities.   In the end, the key thing to recognize is that the electrons are already in a very low energy state, despite how fast they move.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Think about conservation of energy in this situation - if we *could* harness the electric current of orbital electrons to do some form of work, where would the energy be coming from? That the electrons are in stable "orbits"* implies they have given up any excess energy and are in a peaceful lowest-energy state. At the very best maybe we could sap some of the orbital energy, forcing the electons into a lower-energy orbital as they give up their energy, which is not a sustainable source of macroscopic current.

And yes, the randomness of the atoms' orientations would make producing a net current difficult, in the same way that a bunch of jiggling air molecules (air at "rest") don't want to spontaneously spin a fan blade.

(2) There is a form of radioactive decay called Internal Conversion by which a excited nucleus kicks out an electron. Otherwise, ionization or interaction with any other atom will change the "orbit" of an atom's electron.

*("orbit" is in quotes because you shouldn't be visualizing electrons flying around a nucleus like planets around the sun - there's a lot of other physics SE answers that address this)

Comment: yes, the lowest energy state make sense. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Randell Mills founded a company in 1991 claiming to have discovered a limitless power source by forcing electrons in hydrogen to go to a lower energy level than the ground state forming so-called "hydrinos". See [Brilliant Light Power, Inc., formerly BlackLight Power, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brilliant_Light_Power) Until 2006 this company managed to secure $60 million in funds from gullible investors and seems still to be in operation with similar adequate funding. Prominent physicists who stated that this was against the laws of physics where silenced by the lawyers of the company. Thus there are people who think that the energy of atoms can be harnessed and they even make a pretty good living out of it.